# Coloring the text of a div depending on the text value using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to style the text in a “div” when it is populated by a Javascript function. On the initial page load, the “div’s” have no value. There will be no hard-coded value and the "div's" value of "Open" or "Closed" will change twice a day when the Javascript code runs.
Here is a sample of the code I am working with.

```
    <! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Text Color Change</title>
        
        <style>
            .txtbx {
                border: 2px solid #000;
                width: 80px;
                height: 30px;
            }
            .txtbx[value="Open"]{
                color: green;
            }
            .txtbx[value="Closed"]{
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("txtbx1").innerHTML = "Open";
        document.getElementById("txtbx2").innerHTML = "Closed";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="txtbx1" class="txtbx"></div>
        <div id="txtbx2" class="txtbx"></div>
        <button id="btn1" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried the following additional options, none work.

```
.txtbx:has(”Open”) {
Color: green;
}
.txtbx:has(”Closed”) {
Color: red;
}
.txtbx:contains(”Open”) {
Color: green;
}
.txtbx:contains(”Closed”) {
Color: red;
}
```

In my particular situation, changing the color through the Javascript function is not an option. It has to be done via CSS. (Somehow)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attribute:

```js
function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("txtbx1").setAttribute('value',"Open");
  document.getElementById("txtbx2").setAttribute('value',"Closed");
}
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("txtbx2").setAttribute('value',"Open");
  document.getElementById("txtbx1").setAttribute('value',"Closed");
}
```

```css
.txtbx {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
}

.txtbx[value="Open"] {
  color: green;
}

.txtbx[value="Closed"] {
  color: red;
}

.txtbx::before {
  content:attr(value);
}
```

```html
<div id="txtbx1" class="txtbx"></div>
<div id="txtbx2" class="txtbx"></div>
<button id="btn1" onclick="myFunction1()">Click Me</button>
<button id="btn1" onclick="myFunction2()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no CSS selector that is capable of matching element content. Take a look at the [Mozilla Web Docs - CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

However, you can use attribute selectors to style based on the value. Example:

```css
h1[data-text="Hello green world!"] { color: green; }
h1[data-text="Hello red world!"] { color: red; }
```

```html
<h1 data-text="Hello green world!">Hello green world!</h1>
```

Just make sure to have the `data-text` attribute identical to your actual text.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, however, as mentioned in the question, I can't use Javascript in my particular situation. I would like to show the full code, that explains that, but it would take several pages to do so.

Comment: @AubreyLove I'm confused why you can append using JavaScript but not use it to change the style. Anyways, I'll change my answer for another possible solution.

Answer (score -2):

You're looking for a more complex stylesheet solution than css

I'd recommend [sass](https://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: I have not heard of Sass, this will be a learning curve for me. But thanks for the heads-up about it.